# Error while running Appium file

Tags: command-line, java, android

While running Appium file I get the following error:

> Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details.
>
> Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
> Original error: Error occured while starting AndroidBootstrap.
> Original error: Error: Error executing adbExec.
> Original error: 'Command 'C:\Users\vsultan\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ce08171870a97e1704 push C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-android-driver\bootstrap\bin\AppiumBootstrap.jar /data/local/tmp/' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'cannot stat 'C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-android-driver\bootstrap\bin\AppiumBootstrap.jar': No such file or directory'; Code: '1'
> Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'

I have set the environment variable for Android home and the path variable correctly; `adb` command is also working properly on my system.

I have tried re-installing the adb set again and set the environment variable. I don't see anything getting saved under `c:\windows\system32\`.

Comment: It would be useful to also include any research you have done, an explanation of what you were doing when the error occurred, and/or what you have tried to do to correct the issue yourself.

Comment: I re-installed the adb set again and tried to set the environment variable. I don't see anything getting saved under c:\windows\system32\